# Stress test local web application

Tags: ria, stress-testing

How can i test my local RIA?
I need to do a stress test, graph response time and memory usage when user increases.
Do you know any software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RIA tool support is often dictated by the development platform.  For instance if you have GWT and need Javascript support in the tool then you will be pushed to one subset of tools, Silverlight to another, etc...

Looks to your development team, System Requirements Document and Architecture documentation for information on the developmnent toolkits used by your rick internet application.   Once you have good insight there, into both which toolkit and what version then take a look at the commercial and open source tools out there to see which ones support your interface.   There are few things more frustrating than driving a nail with the butt end of a screwdriver, but if your tool and your interface are a poor match you could wind up doing just that.

All of the commercial vendors are offering short term licenses at this point that you should be able to tie directly back to the project budget.   Something to keep in mind on the open source front is that the level of effort on the labor front tends to be higher overall because of the efficiencies built into the commercial tools on the development, monitoring integration and analysis fronts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an open source solution, I can think on Apache JMeter. There are others like Rational Performance Tester or Mercury LoadRunner but those are not free. You might want to verify if there's a trial version out there.